# How can I consume more memory resources than my EC2 instance?

Tags: kubernetes, memory, amazon-ec2, resources, amazon-eks

I am using `t3a.xlarge` instance type, which has 16 gb of memory. When I run kubectl top, I can see my memory usage more than 16gb. Is there something wrong with it? Or Am I missing something? I'd appreciate if anyone can help me grasp this.

$ kubectl top pods

```
NAME                                           CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
Y                                                   112m         39Mi
X-0                                                 865m         7430Mi
X-1                                                 561m         7718Mi
A-0                                                 51m          4158Mi
A-1                                                 28m          2818Mi
A-2                                                 166m         2843Mi
B-0                                                 17m          2583Mi
C-0                                                 203m         6640Mi
C-1                                                 173m         4775Mi
C-2                                                 246m         1446Mi
```

Thanks

Comment: It is using [Virtual memory - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: It seems 40GB in use whereas the actual memory 16GB. How can I calculate the actual memory my deployments using in order to scale up properly? @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Proper setup should be started from defining `requests` and `limits`. Check [Resources utilisation](https://learnk8s.io/production-best-practices#application-development) how it should be done. And [Understanding resource limits in kubernetes: memory](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-memory-6b41e9a955f9) in more details.

Answer (score 1):

The memory you see from kubectl top is the working set which includes the actual physical memory plus the memory mapped files. The memory mapped files are shared by multiple pods. This is why the total can be >16GB if you add them up since the memory mapped files are calculated multiple times. I can update my answer in case you have any further questions.

One comment mentioned virtual memory which would be normally bigger than working set because it includes paged out data.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I want to scale up, but am not sure about the memory. How can I calculate the actual memory my deployments using in order to scale up properly?

Comment: You will get OOM if memory is an issue. Personally I would keep 16GB for now until I see an issue. Scaling up is easy if you have the budget or you can scale out. Scalability is a different topic though.